# How to install pax-jdbc-oracle feature in servicemix?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I could install the feature for mariadb factory. But I have a problems installing the feature for oracle factory in karaf/servicemix. I ran this:

```
karaf> feature:repo-add mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-features/1.4.0/xml/features
karaf> feature:install pax-jdbc-oracle
```

Then, the result throws the next error:

> Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=pax-jdbc-oracle; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.4.0,1.4.0]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=pax-jdbc-oracle)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=1.4.0)(version<=1.4.0))" [caused by: Unable to resolve pax-jdbc-oracle/1.4.0: missing requirement [pax-jdbc-oracle/1.4.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.oracle; type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.4.0,1.4.0]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.oracle/1.4.0: missing requirement [org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.oracle/1.4.0] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=oracle.jdbc)"]]

I tried changing version and adding the oracle driver in `%KARAF_HOME%/system` but no result.
Buddies, Could you give me any clue or solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like that the Oracle JDBC driver (oracle.jdbc.*) is not found or was not assinged in

```
(osgi.wiring.package=oracle.jdbc)
```

so please download a suitable driver from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-ucp-19-7-c-downloads.html i.e. ojdbc8.jar or ojdbc10.jar and add them to classpath

Comment: Yes!!! I installed the ojdbc bundle in the karaf context(karaf>bundle:install wrap:mvn:com.oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.4) , then worked it. Thanks.!!